# ccloud CLI - index out of range [0] with length 0

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-cloud

Running

```
ccloud kafka topic consume <topic> -b --print-key
```

ends with error: `panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0`

What I am wondering is if this is something that can happen or am I looking at some kind of corrupt data in this topic?

Why I ask this, is because I am getting a null pointer exception in one of the services consuming a topic and I am not really sure why it happens since I would expect that even in the case of tombstone record `key` will not be null but `value` can be null (is null if tombstone record). So after filtering out messages that are `null` in value I am not sure what else to do?

[EDIT]: When I try the same thing with a `confluent-kafka-python` library then I get no error, but I do get some null records in the process.
It seems that for now the error in code, when reading from a topic is solved with filtering out null values.

`.filter((key, value) -> key != null || value != null)`

I would have thought `null` keys are skipped?

[EDIT 2] Connected to my other, but related, problem not described here. I had no idea that `.toStream()` after a join with another `KTable` will push down the chain a tombstone record.

Comment: Null keys are not skipped in Kafka Streams

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok, I understand they are not skipped if data is streamed, but for example in join they should be ignored? This issue that I have is related to the second issue where I try to do a join and end up with NPE where I would have expected null keys are ignored and I "only" have to filter out null value messages.

Comment: A join on a stream assumes you have a non-null key, requiring it to be pre-filtered. If you are joining two tables, then you shouldn't have any null keys but you could still have null values

Comment: That I understand but what I had no idea is that after a join of two tables and then converting that result `toStream()` then I am passed a tombstone message also, and then that message will have `value == null`. I wasn't expecting I will get passed a tombstone message after I did a join on two tables.

Comment: But what is still puzzling is why the above error when using `ccloud` and not implementation of `confluent-kafka-python` library.

Comment: ccloud always tries to deserialize the bytearrays, I believe. The Python library will return None if the deserializer fails